# Два элемента на странице. В коде видно, что они не вложены друг в друга, а на деле вложены. Почему?

Tags: php, html

Взгляните на код ниже. Есть div.left-bar и div.main. На первый взгляд они не вложены друг в друга. Но стоит открыть devTools в Chrome, то все не так, как кажется (см. картинку):

```
    <?
    session_start();
    require_once('php/define.php');
    require_once('header.php');
    ?>

    <div class="left-bar">
    <?
    if($_SESSION['user']){
        $conn = new mysqli(SERVER, USER, PWORD, DB);
        if($conn->connect_error){
            exit('Ошибка подключения к базе: ' . $conn->connect_error);
        }

        $sql = 'SHOW TABLES';
        $sql2 = 'SELECT table_comment 
                FROM information_schema.tables
                WHERE table_schema = "TV"';

        $result = $conn->query($sql) or die($conn->error);
        $result2 = $conn->query($sql2) or die($conn->error);

        $tables = $result->fetch_all();
        $tables_comm = $result2->fetch_all();

        echo '<ul class="tables">';
        foreach($tables as $key=>$item){
            echo '<li id="' . $tables[$key][0] . '">' . $tables_comm[$key][0] . '</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul';
    }
    ?>
    </div>

    <div class="main">
    2222
    </div>

    <?
    require_once('footer.php');
    ?>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здесь вообще, я смотрю, div.main и footer оказались в ul. Причем такая картина ТОЛЬКО когда пользователь авторизован, то div.left-bar не пуст. Почему так происходит? И как сделать правильно? Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo '</ul';
```

исправьте на

```
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: Блин, проглядел! Спасибо! Вопрос решен!